# Stop Selenium ChromeWebdriver from Printing/Outputting Manager and Version Info?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am running a script that creates multiple web drivers.  Every time I create a web driver, it prints/outputs the following:

```
====== WebDriver manager ======
Current google-chrome version is 92.0.4515
Get LATEST driver version for 92.0.4515
```

Is there any way to stop this from happening?

Here is my function where I create the webdriver:

```
def create_driver():
    options_ = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options_.add_argument('window-size=100,100')
    options_.add_argument('window-position=0,0')

    return webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), options=options_)
```

Comment: Is there any specific reason why you wanna turned it off  ?

Answer (score 0):

```
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-logging"])
```

This worked for me on Edge, but everything I've tried on Edge seems to work on Chrome since they're both Chromium-based.